# Error app:validateSigningDebug FAILED cuando quiero correr la aplicación

Tags: java, android-studio, keystore

Me aparece este error, ¿alguien sabe como solucionarlo?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
> Task :app:validateSigningDebug FAILED
Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningDebug'.
> Keystore file 'C:\Users\Lulu\AndroidStudioProjects\ElectronicsWorld\app\1.5.10' not found for signing config 'debug'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Comment: Entendería que tu proceso requiere un keystore con una llave en su interior, que pueda usar para firmar el código que estás compilando y empaquetando.

Comment: Muestra tu archivo `build.gradle`. Seguramente modificaste algo que no debías. Sólo debes generar certificados cuando quieras distribuir tu app. A las variantes `debug` las firma automaticamente el AGP con la llave que trae por defecto.

Comment: Se esta leyendo el archivo debug.keystore en otra ubicación, copialo hacía C:\Users\Lulu\AndroidStudioProjects\ElectronicsWorld\app\1.5.10 , aunque veo varias publicaciones en internet que se genera usando keytool esto no es necesario ya que se genera automáticamente dentro de "C:\Users\<user>\.android\"  ,revisa mi respuesta,saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Como cualquier otra aplicación que requiera acceder a una llave asimétrica, necesitas un keystore donde se guarde esa llave que se va a usar para firmar cosas. ¿Entiendes qué quiere decir ésto?

Para que pueda continuar el proceso, debes ir al directorio donde el proceso busca y crear el keystore con la llave dentro (o si ya tienes uno, ponerle allí). Algo similar a:

```
cd ./android/app/

keytool -genkey -v -keystore debug.keystore -storepass android -alias androiddebugkey -keypass android -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

Answer (score 0):

Cuando se muestra el error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

indica que el Keystore para firmar tu aplicación en modo debug no existe.
El archivo para firma en modo debug `debug.keystore` se debería encontrar dentro de la estructura:

```
C:\Users\<user>\.android\debug.keystore
```

Se supone que para el "Keystore debug" no es necesario [crearlo usando keytool](https://coderwall.com/p/r09hoq/android-generate-release-debug-keystores)

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore debug.keystore -storepass android -alias androiddebugkey -keypass android -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

o generarlo desde Android Studio
https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#generate-key

ya que este Keystore se genera automáticamente, pero en este caso Android Studio al parecer trata de leerlo en otra ubicación, para solucionar copia el archivo :

```
C:\Users\<user>\.android\debug.keystore
```

hacia:

```
C:\Users\Lulu\AndroidStudioProjects\ElectronicsWorld\app\1.5.10
```

y vuelve a tratar de generar tu proyecto.